# Are there replays in CoD Mobile?

Tags: call-of-duty-mobile

Is it possible to watch previous matches, or replays in Call of Duty Mobile ?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, as of right now there is no spectator or match replay system available. The best way would be to setup a third party screen recorded app and record all matches, but unfortunately you'll be limited to only your own view.

Answer (score 0):

There are few hacks:

1. You can do screen recording on your mobile. But, it may occupy huge space.
2. Perform live streaming on Facebook with viewer restrictions to private. So that only you can have access to those content and can see it later at any point of time. This requires good network connectivity and will not consume space on your hard disk.